# react-native for androidx,I find this error

Tags: android, react-native

Following is the error message I am getting:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void
> androidx.core.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.()' is inaccessible
> to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule'
> (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule'
> appears in base.apk)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.